# Failed to resolve name 'RSCustomDaxFilter'. It is not a valid table, variable, or function name - не могу понять, как решить проблему в SSRS

Tags: ssrs, dax

Я создаю отчёт в Report Builder и в десктопной версии он прекрасно работает, однако после деплоя отчёта на сервер - отчёт перестаёт визуализироваться. Более того - после подключения к серверу отчётов, он выводит мне такую же ошибку и не работает. Модель куба составлена с помощью Tabular Editor 3, который генерится Power Query. К сожалению, я не имею доступа к настройкам диспетчера конфигурации SSRS.

У меня есть сильное подозрение, что ошибка **Failed to resolve name 'RSCustomDaxFilter'. It is not a valid table, variable, or function name** получается из-за того, что есть какая-то разница в версиях сервера и построителя отчётов (хотя версию построителя скачивал именно с сервера).

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь сможет подсказать решение данной проблемы.